# Stripe Elements - change in layout of 'card-element'

Tags: stripe-payments

I am looking for a way to customise the layout of 'card number' 'expiry date' and 'CCV' fields when using Stripe Elements and injecting these fields through `card.mount('#card-element');` as described in the first example of this page https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js

It puts all the card fields in one row, I want to change that layout and put them in different rows.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this by creating a separate div for each card input (number, expiry, CVC), which you can layout however you like:

```
<div id="example3-card-number"></div>
<div id="example3-card-expiry"></div>
<div id="example3-card-cvc"></div>
```

Then tell Stripe Elements about each one:

```
var cardNumber = elements.create('cardNumber');
cardNumber.mount('#example3-card-number');

var cardExpiry = elements.create('cardExpiry');
cardExpiry.mount('#example3-card-expiry');

var cardCvc = elements.create('cardCvc');
cardCvc.mount('#example3-card-cvc');
```

Ref: https://stripe.dev/elements-examples/ (Example 3)

Comment: how to submit invidual item then ? previously i was using card object

Comment: You can just submit the cardNumber element, & Stripe figures the rest out. Eg: `stripe.createToken(cardNumber).then(function (result) { ... });` Ref: https://stripe.com/docs/js/tokens_sources/create_token?type=cardElement "If applicable, the Element pulls data from other elements you’ve created on the same instance of Elements to tokenize—you only need to supply one Element as the parameter."

Comment: @cometfish you're comment helped me get unstuck. I am setting up metered billing and the documentation for that goes down the path of using createPaymentMethod (versus createToken). The documentation for the method parameters of createPaymentMethod do not mention that other elements get pulled in automatically. Seems easy once you figure it out, but I was stuck on this for over two days.